# I want to drag a row from gridview and drop it on treeview

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop

I am writing a program using ASP .Net MVC. In one of it's page, i want to add two components there. Treeview and gridview.
I want to drag rows from Gridview and drop it on treeview. 
Technically i want to get the ID of dragged row in gridview and add some special condition while dropping it to the tree.

I found great controller for the treeview. but it is only support drag and drop elements within the tree. Here it is, https://gijgo.com/tree
But seems to be they are not providing drag-gable gridviews...
I would really appreciate if you can provide me some sample source code or any link for the above spec. Also it's better if i can use the same treeview with some other draggable gridview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentiond what type of library you are looking for.

Webix library comes out of the box implementation with drag-drop between grid view and tree view. Check this example: https://docs.webix.com/desktop__dnd_external_data.html

For example:

```
{   
    view:"tree", 
    drag:true, 
    select:true,
    data:[],
    externalData:grid2tree
}
```

In the `grid2tree` function you would be writing your business logic.

Download free trial version from here: https://webix.com/download/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am looking for free component. Seems to be this is a paid one.

Comment: How can i download this library?